# Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an : **Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function** error in Chrome with my script.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function showSlidingDiv() {
        $("#slidingDiv").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
    }
    function showSlidingDiv2() {
        $("#slidingDiv2").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
    }         
    function showSlidingDiv3() {
        $("#slidingDiv3").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
    }
</script>
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong here?

Comment: Is there any javascript which calls these functions? Are you including the jquery library?

Answer (score 18):

Chrome does load other libraries that make the use of $ symbol on other purposes,
so you have to use jquery no conflict. on of the way is to change the $ symbol with jQuery

```
$(function(){...});
```

change to

```
jQuery(function(){...});
```

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that jquery was not loaded before run of one of these methods, so or it's not included before run of these methods, or there's some error causing it to not load properly.
Normally this should "just work" (at least not throw that kind of error message)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function showSlidingDiv() {
        $("#slidingDiv").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
    }
    function showSlidingDiv2() {
        $("#slidingDiv2").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
    }         
    function showSlidingDiv3() {
        $("#slidingDiv3").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I was using an old jquery library - it is working now ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No mather the time.. I found a solution that worked for me.

Instead of

```
$("#slidingDiv")
```

try

```
jQuery("#slidingDiv")
```

the other options weren´t usefull for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var j = jQuery;
function showSlidingDiv() {
    j("#slidingDiv").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
}
function showSlidingDiv2() {
    j("#slidingDiv2").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
}         
function showSlidingDiv3() {
    j("#slidingDiv3").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure jQuery.noConflict() isn't being called. Calling it won't allow the use of the $ shorthand notation.