# jQuery - can't get both imported file and own function working

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, menu

First of all I'm far from being a web expert, so please bear my silliness !

I use in one of my PHP files a menu using jQuery. It comes with an external .js file. Actually, this is the *gooeymenu*.
I also use another function for my page.

Thing is : whenever I try to use either my function or the menu alone, it works like a charm. But having both of them in my file ends up allowing only 1 to work.

Here is what I have :

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
---->  <script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="gooeymenu.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gooeymenu.css" />
<ul id="gooeymenu3" class="underlinemenu">
     my list
</ul>

<script>
     gooeymenu.setup({id:'gooeymenu3', fxtime:250})
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function myFunction(){...}
</script>
```

With the previous code, only the gooeymenu works. Calling my function from the PHP code doesn't trigger what it's supposed to do.

Here comes now the other way :

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
<script src="gooeymenu.js"></script>
----> <script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gooeymenu.css" />
<ul id="gooeymenu3" class="underlinemenu">
     my list
</ul>

<script>
     gooeymenu.setup({id:'gooeymenu3', fxtime:250})
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function myFunction(){...}
</script>
```

And this time, my function works fine but not the menu (which is obvious as jQuery was not imported first, but it's meant to show my function DOES work when alone). Notice where the jquery.js has been imported in the 2 examples. Useless to say that I've tried every single combination, also having everything in the  or even above it ...

If any of you have an idea to save a poor soul, I'd be happy to hear it !
Thanks.

**UPDATE ::**

I do have a console error when my function doesn't work (triggered on an onClick from HTML)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function 
myfunction 
onclick
```

As info here's what I do in my function (I know I could avoid jQuery, but I can't in my other page so this is not a solution) :

```
$("#adiv").html("...");
$("#adiv").fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: 2nd example isn't working since jquery-1.8.3.min.js is not loaded...this should always be on top..

Comment: Can you share gooeymenu.js? It would appear that's where the problem is. Does it use jquery? If so, jQuery MUST come first. Where is that you call your function?

Comment: That seems obvious, was pretty much to show that my function works when the menu is ignored ...

Comment: Gooeymenu : http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/gooeymenu.htm
My function is called on an onClick (on a link).

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work, do you get a JavaScript error in the console?

Comment: No error anywhere. Well when the menu doesn't work there's no animation when hovering the elements (the links still work, but that's normal as the list just contains links) and when the function doesn't, the animation doesn't happen either (I'm just setting HTML content and changing visibility of a div in there)

Comment: I actually have another PHP page which is the same situation (except that my own jQuery script uses $(document).ready(function() this time)

Answer (score 1):

Eventually found the solution, guess I was pretty unlucky that the problem was happening on Chrome.

[Solution from Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992723/uncaught-typeerror-property-of-object-object-domwindow-is-not-a-function/9075134#9075134)

Answer (score -1):

first of all gooeymenu seems to be a jquery plugin. so your jQuery source needs to be loaded first:

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="gooeymenu.js"></script>
```

next you should put all of your code inside an domReady-Hander:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    // your code here
});
</script>
```

at last i dont see how your function "myFunction" could work, because you dont call it anywhere!?!?!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    gooeymenu.setup({id:'gooeymenu3', fxtime:250})

    // declare the Function
    function myFunction(){

    }

    // and call it
    myFunction();
});
</script>
```

Comment: i really dont see why my comment gets a downvote. of course setting jQuery in noConflict-mode solved your problem, but my domready handler recommendation is still valid. also gooeymenu is not a good plugin from its architecture, so you shouldnt use that.